# How to consume ADO.NET DataSet as a SSRS 2008 R2 Data Source

Tags: c#, dll, reporting-services, ado.net, ssrs-2008-r2

I am creating reports using SSRS 2008 R2.  I have tried to create Data Source for ADO.NET DataSet but i couldn't find any type for this. 
Please suggest how to using an ADO.NET DataSet as a Reporting Services Data Source in SSRS 2008 R2.

Answer (score 1):

This article titled "Using a Local Reporting Services 2008 Report with an ADO.NET Data Set" looks as though it will answer your question: http://arcanecode.com/2009/02/09/using-a-local-reporting-services-2008-report-with-an-adonet-data-set/

Comment: In article says about ReportViewer control in visual studio (RDLC). but i am looking for SSRS (RDL).

Comment: Ok, sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: Visual Studio does .rdl files. You can start a new report project and add your existing report to it. I use it for most of my reports. The datasources, datasets, and reports will deploy right to your report server.